# Mac doesn't find update to 10.6.0

Tags: macos, updates

I'm trying to update my Mac from 10.5.8 to 10.6.0 in order to install Photoshop CS6 but my Mac doesn't want to find the update when I click *Check for updates*.

What options do I have?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.6 is a major release. I believe you'll have to purchase the upgrade.

Comment: So, following your arguments, you thought Microsoft were giving away Windows 7 for free just because you bought a PC that came with Vista?

Comment: photoshop cs6 still supports windows xp! xp was released on August 24, 2001. mac osx was released  26 October 2007. Its ridicules that i cant use photoshop on it an im forced to update :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the [Mac OS X: Upgrading your software](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT1338) help article, Apple states:

> Mac OS X v10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.4, 10.5, 10.6 and OS X Lion themselves are not free updates, they are reference releases, also called upgrades.

So, you will have purchase [Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573Z/A) <sup>$29</sup> from Apple to update.

Comment: Or even buy Lion!

Answer (score 1):

If you are a MobileMe subscriber you may be able to get 10.6 for free as Apple are giving away upgrade DVD's. You can read more here:

http://9to5mac.com/2012/04/18/apple-throws-mobileme-users-a-free-version-of-snow-leopard-to-update-to-icloud/

I managed to get hold of one for my Dad.